# Money transfer from India

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, gift-tax

I am a green card holder in US, my mother wants to gift me $6000. I want to know if there are any laws that prevent me to accepting the monies as gift? Will I have to declare it in my return? Will she have to provide an6 kind of documentation before accepting this money? Will I get in trouble with IRS?

Thanks 
Ishleen

Comment: Welcome, @itk. This question, and variations on it, has been asked and answered before. In the United States, the tax on gifts falls on the person giving it.